# PHP CentOS OpenOffice Headless

Tags: centos, openoffice.org

I have a (dv) server from mediatemple running CentOS.

I am trying to convert .doc or .ppt to .pdf files using php shell_exec

After searching through stackoverflow and dozens of sites I ran this command under root through ssh.

```
yum install openoffice.org-headless
```

Then I ran, `soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard &` which I thought was supposed to run it headless on the server.

I keep running into this error.

```
# javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
```

How can I install this Java Runtime Environment and then what should I be using for the shell_exec command?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to upgrade your DV.  I was running into the same issue after I installed Open Office.  I was running the 512MB virtual server. I upgraded to the 2048MB virtual server and was able to run open office headless without any issues.

You do not have to install the java runtime as it is already installed.